# Where do I receive print commands in Python

Tags: python

I have a simple python program:

```
 print 'hi'
```

Where do I execute this to receive the print statement? Excuse my ignorance, I am just learning python.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: It receives the command at the terminal, this is a technique of console input/output.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. You can save it in a file. Then run `python yourfile.py` to execute the command. The typical file extension for Python source code is `.py`.
2. You can run the Python interpreter. This is a way to quickly test Python code without having to save it to a file. Simply type `python` and you will see a few lines telling you the version of your Python interpreter followed by `>>>`, which is the interpreter prompt. Any Python statement you type here is immediately executed and the results printed out:

   ```
   burhan@sandbox:~$ python
   Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07)
   [GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> print 'hi'
   hi
   >>>
   ```

   To exit the interpreter, type `quit()`.
3. A third way is to use the `-c` flag of the Python command. This tells Python to immediately execute the code following the `-c` flag, like this:

   ```
   burhan@sandbox:~$ python -c 'print "hi"'
   hi
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this documentation on using the python interpreter: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html

## first,

either add the path to your Python interpreter into your environment variables, or navigate to that path (usually c:\Python27\python.exe on windows)

## then,

type "`python`" into the command prompt.

Doing so will start the python interpreter and will look something like this:
[image: python interpreter]

then you just type in your command:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open `python IDLE` in windows or just type `python` in  terminal that

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Sundar>python
Python 2.7.5 Stackless 3.1b3 060516 (default, May 21 2013, 17:59:42) [MSC v.1500
 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 'hi'
hi
>>>
```

if u type that u get the response.

**Adddtionally** : there are lot resources and methods

1. create a file `something.py` and in command line u move to loaction where u saved python file  and type `python something.py`

   2. u can do online check this site [repl](http://repl.it/languages/Python)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way for a new user to learn Python is to use IDLE, which comes with the Python installation. Here is a simple and easy explanation on how to get started:

http://www.annedawson.net/Python_Editor_IDLE.htm